# jQuery data store an object with single or double quotes

Tags: jquery, html

When I use data attribute to store some data, and use jQuery to get these data, but there is a different data conversion for single and double quotes, one is object and one is string.

Does anyone has idea for this? Thanks.

[jsfiddle test](http://jsfiddle.net/wlon/67kgkvx5/)

```
<div id="test1" data-test='{"k1":"v1","k2":2}'>
    single qoutes data<br/>
</div>
<div id="test2" data-test="{'k1':'v1','k2':2}">
    double qoutes data<br/>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var data1=$("#test1").data("test");
   var data2=$("#test2").data("test");
   $("#test1").append(typeof data1);
   $("#test2").append(typeof data2);
</script>
```

Comment: Because for valid json format you need to enclose the keys and string values in `"` not `'`

Comment: `JSON.parse("{'k1':'v1','k2':2}")` will give an error where as `JSON.parse('{"k1":"v1","k2":2}')` returns an object

Comment: aha, I see. that is the root cause. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes in json in does matter whether it is single quotes or double quotes. for json format it is necessary to enclose key and value in **double quotes** other wise it will not parse as json. You can validate both values here for [validation](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) data with single quotes will give you error **Strings should be wrapped in double quotes**.